# Apache PDFBox missing classes when run on Ubuntu server (18.04)

Tags: java, ubuntu, pdfbox

I am receiving the following error when trying to locate the Version class from Apache PDFBox command line tools:

```
$ java org.apache.pdfbox.tools.Version -cp pdfbox-tools-3.0.0-RC1.jar
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.pdfbox.tools.Version
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: picocli/CommandLine$IVersionProvider
```

Also receiving this error when run a different way:

```
$ java -jar pdfbox-tools-3.0.0-RC1.jar Version ../sample_pdfs/test_1.pdf
no main manifest attribute, in pdfbox-tools-3.0.0-RC1.jar
```

Has anyone else had any similar problems with running the PDFBox tools on the command line under Ubuntu Server 18.04?  New to Java and I have loaded and tested small program builds on the command line and they build and run fine. All java and javac components are recently added and the CLASSPATH is set. Not sure what I am missing. But based on the PDFBox samples for command line, this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the command line tools, you need to use pdfbox-app, as described [here](https://pdfbox.apache.org/2.0/commandline.html). The pdfbox-tools subproject is for the tools API.

Comment: I did try the app version prior to trying the tools only version. But it seems that there is an issue with the version 3.0.0. All works fine with running version 2.0.23. Note that version 3.0.0 works fine when tested on Windows 10, but fails when run on Ubuntu 18.04 with many errors. I cannot post then here due to the amount of errors returned and Stackoverflows limit on size of Comments. But 18.04 works fine with version 2.0.23 so something is missing in the latest version that Ubuntu needs (it shows many errors related to the package picocli. And also awt headless issues.

Comment: if you insist on running pdf-tools from the command line then yes, you'll need picocli in the class path and you'd have to tell what class you want to run. pdfbox-app should run by itself. Your comment is unclear whether pdfbox-app has the same problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion in my prior response.  Yes, I am referring to the app (not the tools). There is an issue with pdfbox-app that returns errors on Ubuntu Server 18.04 that are not present when the prior version is run. So, yes, I am indeed running the app version. The problem I encounter is when trying to run version 3.0.0 of the app on 18.04 (though version 2.0.23 app run fine on 18.04 server).

Comment: I have ubuntu on an old machine, I got this error https://askubuntu.com/questions/695560/assistive-technology-not-found-awterror after I had installed a headless java. After deinstalling it, it somehow installed a java that worked properly.

Comment: I just fixed another problem on headless systems, you can try with a snapshot here https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/

Comment: Thank you - Below is shown when I run the latest.  Without changing anything on the server, the prior version runs perfectly (v2.0.23). It appears that something changed between that version and app version 3.0.0. Confusing, because it is the same java installation for both, but just run from different directory (v3.0.0 dir versus v2.0.23 directory) where the app and supporting jars are copied.


$ java -jar pdfbox-app-3.0.0-20210428.032646-2607.jar
Exception in thread "main" picocli.CommandLine$InitializationException: Could not inject spec
        at picocli.CommandLine$Model$Command

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-5181 you need to install a jdk that has awt

Comment: Understood and thanks. But I want to make sure I totally understand this before changing jdk. The prior version runs perfectly. So something changed in v3.0.0. The system is only being used as headless server (not sure this will be a problem with awt but wanted to point out my particular use situation). As it stands, I can run pdfbox-app jar for v2.0.23 without awt. It seems that perhaps a new feature or default was added in v.3.0.0 that references awt. I tried looking at changes in v3 but there are many and I could not tell what the tie-in with awt might be. Tx for your patience and help!

Comment: It's picocli, which does some wild stuff with reflection which instantiates the PDFDebugger class even if not used. This has now been fixed in the snapshot.